# UnsupportedOperationException when mocking com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort with PowerMockito

Tags: serial-port, powermockito

I am trying to write some test for my PortHandler class. 
When trying to mock SerialPort object I get following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: initializeLibrary is native
    at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.initializeLibrary(SerialPort.java)
    at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.<clinit>(SerialPort.java:238)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:47)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:69)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1895)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:108)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:61)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:126)
    at com.project.serial.PortHandlerTest.testClosePort(PortHandlerTest.java:72)
```

My Test class :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SerialPort.class})
public class PortHandlerTest{

@Mock
SerialPortMessageListener mockedPortListener;

@Mock
OutputStream mockedOS;

PortHandler portHandler;


@Test
public void testConnect() {

    String portName = "testPort";

    SerialPort mockedPort = PowerMockito.mock(SerialPort.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SerialPort.class);

    Mockito.when(SerialPort.getCommPort(portName)).thenReturn(mockedPort);
    Mockito.when(mockedPort.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(mockedOS);

    portHandlerService = new PortHandlerServiceImpl(portName, mockedPortListener);      
    portHandlerService.connect();

}
```

Line 53 is `SerialPort mockedPort = PowerMockito.mock(SerialPort.class);`

List of my dependencies :

- junit 4.12
- mockito-core 2.22.0
- powermock-api-mockito2 2.0.0-beta.5
- powermock-module-junit4 2.0.0-beta.5

Even after throwing an exception the execution continues and I get valid test results.

Thanks for help
PacHOOk